# How can I resole a fatal error that appeard after updating Craft CMS?

Tags: php, yii, updates, craftcms

I want to update to a newer craft CMS version, and I tried to do it in the control panel. The latest available version was `3.7.12`. After I clicked on `update all` I got the following error:

**Fatal error**: Declaration of

> craft\helpers\FileHelper::getExtensionByMimeType($mimeType): string
> must be compatible with
> yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper::getExtensionByMimeType($mimeType,
> $preferShort = false, $magicFile = null) in
> **/var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/FileHelper.php** on line
> **719**

Later, I updated successfully to version 3.8.2 using the terminal. All dependencies are also updated and `yiisoft/yii2` version is set to `2.0.45`. However, the problem still stays.

The solutions I tried are the ones [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/40816/3-7-9-and-above-update-issue) but it didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `composer install` in `/var/www/html` fixed the issue